# CSS Styles not being removed after class is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am sitting with an issue where CSS styles don't get removed from an anchor tag when the css class is removed via AJAX, it only happens on a mobile device. This doesn't happen when using a desktop browser.

Have a look [here](http://thecontentbar.dedicated.co.za/Reviews-in-Johannesburg) using a mobile device.

You will note that the filters turn red when you select them, but deselecting them doesn't remove the red.

The code that is used there:

```
$('.tagsContainer .tagsContainerA').click(function () {
    vm.alphabet("");
    clearAlphabet();
    $('.pagination.alphabet .alphabetAll').addClass('currentPage');
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Any ideas what could be causing this on a mobile device?

Comment: have you checked on a mobile device whether the class is really removed or not? also can you provide css for the `.selected`?

Comment: What mobile device are you using / which browser/ version?

Comment: `$('.tagsContainer .tagsContainerA').on('touchstart click',function() { ... }`

try using `touchstart ` for mobile devices and also you've defined `:hover` effect also which also 'may be' causing the issue.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay thanks that does the trick

Comment: @Armand then I should post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with the `hover`, not the click function.

This happens because the `hover` is triggered in mobile while the element is `focused` also.

Just add this to your css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .places-filter .places-tags li:hover {
        background-color: #d1d1d1;
        background: #d1d1d1;
    }
}
```

This way you will 'disable' the hover function and only have the click one in mobile.

Another solution is placing the hover effect only in screens bigger than X amount.